# Ordenar Array de un file_get_html

Tags: php, array

Tengo este extraño caso, espero me ayuden. Estoy Tratanto de ordenar el resultado de un array Extraído con `DOM`  pero no me funciona

Código:

```
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://Google.com/');

$links = array();

$orden= array_splice($links, 0,0,54) // utilizo esta función para ordenar los arrays y mostrar los últimos 

foreach($html->find('a') as $a) {
 $orden[] = $a->href;
}
print_r($orden);
```

RESUTADO

> Array ( [0] =>
>
> 1- link 1 2- link 2  3 - link 3 ............. (Muestra como 50
>   elementos y quiero limitarlo a 5 por ejemplo )
>
> 1- link 1 2- link 2  3 - link 3 4- link 4 5- link 5

En resumen `array_splice` promete hacer eso pero no funciona, ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Yo veo que utilizas `$links` justo despues de iniciarlizarlo, por tanto cuando tienes `$orden= array_splice($links, 0,0,54)` el array `$links` como esta vacio devolvera un arreglo vacio. Eso o sino coloca tu codigo de manera que podamos entenderlo

Comment: Hola Amigo lo siento mucho no se porque aparece el post de esa manera, ya que lo envio muy ordenado, y $links supuestamente no esta vacio tiene el arreglo de arrays de $html pero dime vez un error ?

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que se ve en el codigo de tu pregunta, no sabemos como llenas `$inks` desde `$html`. Por favor comparte el codigo completo o relevante para hacer la evaluacion correspondiente.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero intento editarlo y al colocar ` ` en el código no lo resalta, no entiendo.          Ah y referente al código esta completo si lo ejecutas en PHP te dará el resultado mencionado

Comment: Veo que me dara el resultado, pero `$links` sigue siendo una variable que no usas en absoluto. Puedes obtenerlo imprimiendo el contenido de `$links` en la pagina.

Comment: Si, pero dime Cual será el problema que Array_splice no ordena el array? Ya que lo he puesto dentro del foreach y nada, aunque lo probe con un listado de nombre y allí si trabajo pero era un Array no extraído con DOM , no comprendo que pasa porque Print muestra el Array valido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según lo que leo [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-splice.php)  `array_splice` no sirve para ordenar un `array`.

```
array array_splice ( array &$input , 
                     int $offset [, int $length = 0 [, mixed $replacement = array() ]] )
```

Lo que hace es partiendo de un `$offset` hasta un `$length` elimina esos índices y los reemplaza por lo contenido en `$replacement`.
La referencia dice que si `$replacement` no es un `array`, será convertido a uno.

En tu caso pasas llamas a `array_splice($links,0,0,54)` esto hace que no se produzca ningún cambio en el `array $links` ya que `$length` es `0`.

Tal vez estés utilizando la función incorrecta.

Aquí te dejo unos links de ayuda:

- [Array Sorting](http://php.net/manual/es/array.sorting.php)
- [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/es/book.array.php)

Comment: Hola @Alan muchas gracias por interesarte en mi pregunta! Y pues le informo ya encontré el problema el array lo tengo que limitar al inicio del `foreach` al parecer deben estar combinado los resultados para que funcione el limitador `splice` Pero muchas gracias aceptare tu respuesta! Pero una pregunta rápida Ud, puede utilizar y conoce la libreria DOM esque tengo unas dudas al respecto

Comment: Hola, si tienes una nueva pregunta hazla de la misma manera que hiciste esta, así todos tenemos la oportunidad de ayudarte y responderte. que bueno que lo hayas podido solucionar!

Comment: OK esta bien muchas Gracias :)